# If statement being disregarded. Python

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to make this high score system, where if your score is greater than a score saved in a text file it will override that text file and replace the previous score holders score with yours.

One problem is that no matter what your score is it just simply overrides it.

```
hs = open("score.txt")
hss = [line for line in hs.readlines()]
hsss = hs.readlines()
hs.close()

while True:
    hs2 = open('score.txt', 'w')
    for line in hss[1:]:
        hs2.write(line)
    if str(score) <= str(hs2):    
        hs2.write(str(score))
```

Any sugestions too fix?

Comment: Fix your indentation to reflect the code you are actually running. The above would give a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `score` and where did it come from?  Also, why are you trying to perform an inequality on *strings*?

Comment: @Makoto Score is a number that gets auto increased. The code worked not it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Your main mistake is that you are comparing the current score with a file object, `hs2`. Try printing the two strings you compare and the problem will be obvious.

As for the solution: First, find the previous high score. Ensure that both your score (`score`) and the previous high score are compared as integers. Otherwise, "2" compares after "10", "11" etc. when sorted alphabetically as strings.

Comment: before i came here i tried with hs, hss,  hsss and hs2 both made no difference.

Comment: Of course not. Trying things at random is no way to solve a problem.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I have been playing with it for 20 mins now and still nothing.

Comment: Stop playing and focus on understanding your code. Run each line in the interpreter and inspect the resulting variables. Where is the current high score? If you don't know, your first problem is in the lines you've already written (or been given).

Comment: Oh and use more specific names than `hssssss`. Every variable in your program has _something_ to do with high scores; but what? Better names will help you understand your program.